# Response.Write after Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, redirect

I want to when push save button write a javascript message and Response.Redirect same page as empty form (RawUrl) on asp.net

```
 Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Record successful.')</script>");
 Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

But I cant see any message just redirecting page.  How can I show a message and then redirect same page?

Comment: A better user experience is to use AJAX and redirect when returning success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do redirect via Javascript after alert has been shown.

```
Response.Write(@"
     <script>
        alert('Record successful.');
        window.location = '" + Request.RawUrl + @"';
    </script>
");
```

You can also set timeout

```
Response.Write(@"
     <script>
        alert('Record successful.');
        setTimeout(function(){            
            window.location = '" + Request.RawUrl + @"';
        }, 2000);
    </script>
");
```

And Javascript will redirect user 2s after clicking message box.

Comment: However use location.replace or a setTimeout to not break the back button

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan I want to ask something too.  Ok then,  if I want to redirect same page but not empty form. I guess I cant use RawUrl.  Just I dont want to lose  session. How can I do that?

Comment: Ask a new question